# Remove duplicates from a table based on a non-duplicated field

Tags: mysql

I need to remove some duplicate data based on a non-duplicated field.

Sample Data:

```
|status|Size|id#   |income|scan_date |
|  0   | 3  |123456| 1000 |2015-10-16|
|  1   | 3  |123456| 1000 |2015-10-16|
|  1   | 4  |112345|  900 |2015-09-05|
|  0   | 7  |122345|  700 |2015-10-01|
```

When the id# and scan_date are the same, I need to remove only the rows where the status is "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from table
where status=0
and (id, scan_date) in
(select id, scan_date from
(select id, scan_date from table
group by id, scan_date
having count(*) >=2) t1)
```

You need the extra subquery in mysql, since mysql does not allow to select from the table being updated or deleted from.

Update: see [this sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20624/2) I created. I think you removed the subquery with the t1 alias, even though I explicitly warned you that it is important!

Comment: I get the following error when I try to replace 'table' with the actual table name: "You can't specify target table 'stdnt_data_copy' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Did you include the additional subquery with the t1 alias?

Comment: I did include the subquery with the t1 alias.  I looked into the version of mysql that is running on the server here, it is actually quite old, 4.1.22.  Could that be part of the problem?